# Criar grid Master/Detail

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

Como eu faço para criar dois grid Master/Detail no Xamarin.Forms(Android/IOS)? A dificuldade não está na criação do grid, mas sim implementar o Master/Detail

Comment: não entendi sua pergunta, seria um master/detail dentro de outro?

Comment: @M.Bertolazo, já resolvi. Criei um grid e um evento de SelectedRow e quando eu clico nessa row, passo um id para o outro grid e abro os itens referentes a essa venda/orçamento nesse último grid.